# Processes launched via Process.Start() is limited to 2 gigabytes of memory

Tags: python, c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have an `asp.net` backend app that needs to trigger a large python script  through CLI with `StartProcessInfo()`.

Code that launches python with arguments using `Process.Start()`:

```
public void Func(args){
        
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(); 

    psi.FileName = @"C:\path\to\python.exe";
    string script = @"script.py";
    psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\path\to\dir";

    psi.Arguments = $"{script} {args}";

    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

    string errors = string.Empty;
    string results = string.Empty;
    Debug.WriteLine(psi.Arguments);
    using (Process process = Process.Start(psi))
    {
        results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(results);
    Debug.WriteLine(errors);
}
```

my problem is, when the script is ran by `Process.Start()` it's memory usage rises to 3-4 GB of ram, then falls down rapidly to 2.1-2.4 GB of ram and freezes even though i have 8 GB of free memory.

and when i launch the script manually it runs perfectly fine with 5.5 GB of ram used.

is there a way to trigger the python script with arguments without having it memory constrained to 2 GB?

I'm using `.net` x64 version 4.7.2 on win10x64 with if it helps.

---

EDIT: This question might be considered to be a duplicate as there are already other questions about limitations of C# application. But, this question is focused to executing other application (`python.exe`) and avoiding inheritance of those limitations between original ASP.NET app and other `python.exe` app. This scenario is not mentioned in linked-duplicate question and might have different solution/answer.

Comment: You're running on an x64 machine, but is your code compiled into an x64 assembly?

Comment: @WaiHaLee Yes, x64 assembly

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem by making a script attached to C# which acts as an interface between ASP.NET and the detached process(high memory usage). Thus, bypassing memory limitations or rather, the whole ASP.NET.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make sure you've read the guidelines for posting questions and answers. As a rule of thumbs, post code and clear descriptions of solutions. Do not assume that the person that first asked the question knows what you are talking about.